# Inserting MYSQL Data with Dapper gives "Connection must be valid and open" error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, blazor, dapper

I'm trying to get more familiar with Blazor Server database connections, but whenever I try to insert data it gives me the "Connection must be valid and open" error. I'm confused because I am querying the data earlier in the razor component. I am using Dapper for model conversion.

Data Access class

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
    {
        //Code from Timothy Corey
        public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters, string connectionString)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var rows = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);

                return rows.ToList();
            }
        }
        public Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters, string connectionString)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                return connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

Razor Component

```
@inject IDataAccess _data
@inject IConfiguration _config

<h3>MaintenanceList</h3>

@if (mLog == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Shop</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in mLog)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Type</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>$@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.Cost)</td>
                    <td>@item.Shop</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<button @onclick=InsertData>insert data</button>

@code {
    List<MaintenanceLog> mLog;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string sql = "select * from maintenancelog";

        mLog = await _data.LoadData<MaintenanceLog, dynamic>(sql, new {  }, _config.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    }

    private async Task InsertData()
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO maintenancelog (Title, Type, Description, Date, Cost, Shop) VALUES (@Title, @Type, @Description, @Date, @Cost, @Shop); ";
        await _data.SaveData(sql, new { Title = "Tire Replacement", Type = "General Maintenance", Description = "tires repaired", Date = new DateTime(), Cost = 345.67, Shop = "Discount Tire" }, _config.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    }
 }
```

I know my connection string is working because the table in the razor component is populating, and I have tried the SQL command in MYSQL Workbench, so I think it is something with my Data Access class, but I can't figure out what. I've also tried making a simpler table but I get the same result

Comment: ExecuteAsync returns Task<int>, so shouldn't SaveData do the same?

Comment: hi @Jarrett,
Let adjust your SaveData with async since you are using `await _data.SaveData` in `InsertData()`


```public async Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters, string connectionString)
{
 using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
  return await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After pulling a lot of hair out and trying other people's projects, I realized it was my dapper version. Downgrading to version 2.0.35 fixed my issue, and anything above would either give me the same issue or an occasional object reference exception

Comment: Seems unlikely.